# Having a single method in a base class able to allocate for child classes

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr

I'm trying to have a common base/helper class that allocates shared_ptrs for the calling class, but I'm having problems getting it to work in derived classes.

```c
#include <memory>

template<typename T>
struct SPAlloc {

    virtual ~SPAlloc() {}

    template<typename ...Args>
    static std::shared_ptr<T>
    Alloc(Args&&... params) {
        return std::make_shared<T>(std::forward<Args>(params)...);
    }


    template<class U, typename ...Args>
    static std::shared_ptr<U>
    Alloc(Args&&... params) {
        return std::make_shared<U>(std::forward<Args>(params)...);
    }
};

class Base : public SPAlloc<Base> {
public:
    virtual ~Base() {};
};

class Child : public Base {
public:
    virtual ~Child() {};
};

typedef std::shared_ptr<Base> pBase;
typedef std::shared_ptr<Child> pChild;

int main() {
    pBase base = Base::Alloc();
    pChild child = Child::Alloc();
}
```

I understand that the `class Base : public SPAlloc<Base>` means that `T` in the template is going to be `Base`, which is why I created the second Alloc. The second alloc needs to be called like `Child::Alloc<Child>()`.

Is there a way to write this `Alloc` so that the compiler can deduce the class I'm calling Alloc with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: No, there isn't.

Long answer: The point is that `Alloc` is not aware of `Child` unless explicitly told, so where would that information come from? The call to `Child::Alloc()` is a call to `Base::Alloc()`, which is a call to `SPAlloc<Base>::Alloc()` and there, all information about `Child` is lost.

The easiest solution is using a free function, but that function already exists and it's called: `std::make_shared`. Maybe consider using it directly and safe yourself the trouble with `SPAlloc` altogether.

Alternatively, if you want to overwrite `SPAlloc<T>::Alloc()` for each child, you won't need the base class `SPAlloc` at all, just add the method to each class, that's probably easier than using a base class.

Comment: I thought as much. I was hoping to have a single wrapper for all the classes and have the compiler /do what I want/. The reason I wanted to wrap std::make_shared is in case I want to change the way the classes are allocated in the future (although, I guess I can use allocate_shared). Anyway, for now, I'm going to just have a stand-alone function that wraps make_shared

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do this you need all your objects to inherit from `Spalloc` with themselves as a template parameter, even your children classes :

```
class Child : public SPAlloc<Child>, public Base {
public:
    virtual ~Child() {};
public:
   using SPAlloc<Child>::Alloc;
};
```

You can also simply just use std::make_shared :)